How can I get grub menu in dual boot?
recently I installed Ubuntu alongside windows 11. Ubuntu worked on first boot, updated as usual. After that grub menu didn't appear, I can't get into Ubuntu.
Tried

Bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

Did not work.
Please help.
Remember I can't get into Ubuntu at all so no linux commands please.

Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Have you tried going into UEFI/BIOS setup and change the boot order to Ubuntu first? If that does not work, boot from the Ubuntu Live Installation USB and choose Try Ubuntu. Then follow the instructions for boot-repair, here. Then click the Create a Boot-Info Summary button. Finally edit your question above and add the link to the uploaded report.

This question is similar to: How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
